# Losing an hour when returning a January 1970 Date from milliseconds

Tags: java, date, milliseconds, date-formatting

I have the following code that takes a String of milliseconds (will be from an RSS feed so will be a String, the example below is a quick test program) and converts those millis into a Date object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ms = "1302805253";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(ms));

    try {
        String dateFormat = dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("Date Format = " + dateFormat);

        Date dateParse = dateFormatter.parse(dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Date Parse  = " + dateParse);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}


Output:
    Date Format = Fri, 16 Jan 1970 02:53:25 GMT
    Date Parse  = Fri Jan 16 03:53:25 GMT 1970
```

As you can see, between the formatting of the calendar object and parsing of the resulting String, an hour is being lost.  Also, the formatting of the output has changed.  Can anyone help me as to why this is happening, and how to get around it?  I want the Date object to be  the same format as the "Date Format" output.

Comment: The issue is that Britain was on BST (=GMT+1) or the whole year in 1970 as a trial. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238172/why-does-an-hour-get-added-on-to-java-util-date-for-dates-before-nov-1-1971

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's happening because the UK didn't *actually* use GMT in 1970, and Java has a bug around that... it will *format* a date in 1970 as if the UK were using GMT, but without actually changing the offset. Simple example:

```
Date date = new Date(0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Result:

```
01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 GMT
```

Note that it claims it's 1am GMT... which is incorrect. It *was* 1am in Europe/London time, but Europe/London wasn't observing GMT.

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) gets this right in that it prints out BST - but Joda Time doesn't like *parsing* values with time zone abbreviations. However, you can get it to use time zone *offets* instead:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(0, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(
            "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

        String text = formatter.print(date); // 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 +0100
        System.out.println(text);

        DateTime parsed = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
        System.out.println(parsed.equals(date)); // true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816574/642706) is correct.

## java.time

Let’s run the same input through java.time to see the results.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST`, `EST`, or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).  So we use [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London).

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
String input = "1302805253";
long millis = Long.parseLong ( input );
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( millis );
```

Apply a time zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/London" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone ( zoneId );
```

Dump to console. We see indeed that `Europe/London` time is an hour ahead of UTC at that moment. So the time-of-day is `02` hours rather than `01` hours. Both represent the same simultaneous moment on the timeline, just viewed through the lenses of two different [wall-clock times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 1302805253 | instant: 1970-01-16T01:53:25.253Z | zdt: 1970-01-16T02:53:25.253+01:00[Europe/London]

## Whole seconds

By the way, I suspect your input string represents *whole* seconds since epoch of 1970 UTC rather than *milliseconds*. Interpreted that as seconds we get a date in 2011, in the month this Question posted.

```
String output = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( Long.parseLong ( "1302805253" ) ).atZone ( ZoneId.of ( "Europe/London" ) ).toString ();
```

> 2011-04-14T19:20:53+01:00[Europe/London]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.